# How to align buttons and checkboxes in different lines in java

Tags: java, layout

Well I am a newbie in Java and i have written this simple case converter program:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class caseconversion extends JFrame{

    private JTextField tf;
    private JCheckBox boldbox;
    private JCheckBox italicbox;
    private JButton up;
    private JButton low;

    public caseconversion(){

        super ("Case Converter");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        tf=new JTextField("Hello whats up Buddy !!",25);
        tf.setFont(new Font("Segoe Print",Font.PLAIN,15));
        add(tf);
        boldbox = new JCheckBox("Bold");
        italicbox = new JCheckBox("Italic");
        add(boldbox);
        add(italicbox);

        up=new JButton("Upper Case");
        low=new JButton("Lowercase");
        add(up);
        add(low);

        HandlerClass handler = new HandlerClass();
        boldbox.addItemListener(handler);
        italicbox.addItemListener(handler);
        up.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                tf.setText(tf.getText().toUpperCase());
            }
        }
                );
        low.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                tf.setText(tf.getText().toLowerCase());
            }
        }
       );           
    }

    private class HandlerClass implements ItemListener {
        //For Checkboxes
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event){
            Font font= null;

            if(boldbox.isSelected()&&italicbox.isSelected())
                font = new Font("Segoe Print",Font.BOLD + Font.ITALIC ,15);
            else if(boldbox.isSelected())
                font = new Font("Segoe Print",Font.BOLD ,15);
            else if(italicbox.isSelected())
                font = new Font("Segoe Print",Font.ITALIC ,15);
            else
                font= new Font("Segoe Print",Font.PLAIN,15);

            tf.setFont(font);

        }
    }
public static void main(String arg[]){

        caseconversion go = new caseconversion();
        go.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        go.setSize(400,250);
        go.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Its working fine but i want to display `JTextField tf` in center,`boldbox`&`italicbok` on next line in center and Similarly `JButtons` on 3rd line in Center Can you please tell me how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most simple solution (with minimal changes to the original code) is probably to put each row into one JPanel (where each JPanel has a FlowLayout), and arrange these 3 panels using a GridLayout

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class caseconversion extends JFrame{

    private JTextField tf;
    private JCheckBox boldbox;
    private JCheckBox italicbox;
    private JButton up;
    private JButton low;

    public caseconversion(){

        super ("Case Converter");
        setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));

        JPanel p = null;

        p = new JPanel();
        tf=new JTextField("Hello whats up Buddy !!",25);
        tf.setFont(new Font("Segoe Print",Font.PLAIN,15));
        p.add(tf);
        add(p);

        p = new JPanel();
        boldbox = new JCheckBox("Bold");
        italicbox = new JCheckBox("Italic");
        p.add(boldbox);
        p.add(italicbox);
        add(p);

        p = new JPanel();
        up=new JButton("Upper Case");
        low=new JButton("Lowercase");
        p.add(up);
        p.add(low);
        add(p);

        HandlerClass handler = new HandlerClass();
        boldbox.addItemListener(handler);
        italicbox.addItemListener(handler);
        up.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                    tf.setText(tf.getText().toUpperCase());
                }
            }
            );
        low.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                    tf.setText(tf.getText().toLowerCase());
                }
            }
            );           
    }

    private class HandlerClass implements ItemListener {
        //For Checkboxes
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event){
            Font font= null;

            if(boldbox.isSelected()&&italicbox.isSelected())
                font = new Font("Segoe Print",Font.BOLD + Font.ITALIC ,15);
            else if(boldbox.isSelected())
                font = new Font("Segoe Print",Font.BOLD ,15);
            else if(italicbox.isSelected())
                font = new Font("Segoe Print",Font.ITALIC ,15);
            else
                font= new Font("Segoe Print",Font.PLAIN,15);

            tf.setFont(font);

        }
    }
    public static void main(String arg[]){

        caseconversion go = new caseconversion();
        go.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        go.setSize(400,250);
        go.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Note that you also have to think about the resizing behavior. Should these 3 rows always span the full height of the frame, or should they be compactly pushed to the top border of the frame?

However, a general hint (that seems to be underrated by newbies) is **nesting**: There's nothing wrong with creating a new JPanel in order to achieve a particular layout. Usually, a more "clean" solution to achieve this is to group several GUI components logically (and not re-using such a helper variable like the `JPanel p` that I used in the example).

Answer (score 0):

If you using eclipse, i know a way that helped me. 
JWindowbuilder: http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/

If not you should look at this too:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

greetings Visores

i changed it the way you want with the WindowBuilder, i hope you like it :D

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class caseconversion extends JFrame {

    private JTextField tf;
    private JCheckBox boldbox;
    private JCheckBox italicbox;
    private JButton up;
    private JButton low;
    private Box verticalBox;
    private Box horizontalBox;
    private Box horizontalBox_1;
    private Box horizontalBox_2;
    private Component horizontalStrut;
    private Component horizontalStrut_1;
    private Component verticalStrut;

    public caseconversion() {

        super("Case Converter");
        HandlerClass handler = new HandlerClass();
        getContentPane().setLayout(
                new BoxLayout(getContentPane(), BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

        verticalBox = Box.createVerticalBox();
        getContentPane().add(verticalBox);

        horizontalBox = Box.createHorizontalBox();
        verticalBox.add(horizontalBox);

        horizontalStrut_1 = Box.createHorizontalStrut(20);
        horizontalBox.add(horizontalStrut_1);

        tf = new JTextField("Hello whats up Buddy !!", 25);
        tf.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(2147483647, 60));
        horizontalBox.add(tf);
        tf.setFont(new Font("Segoe Print", Font.PLAIN, 15));

        horizontalStrut = Box.createHorizontalStrut(20);
        horizontalBox.add(horizontalStrut);

        horizontalBox_1 = Box.createHorizontalBox();
        verticalBox.add(horizontalBox_1);
        boldbox = new JCheckBox("Bold");
        horizontalBox_1.add(boldbox);
        italicbox = new JCheckBox("Italic");
        horizontalBox_1.add(italicbox);
        italicbox.addItemListener(handler);
        boldbox.addItemListener(handler);

        horizontalBox_2 = Box.createHorizontalBox();
        verticalBox.add(horizontalBox_2);

        up = new JButton("Upper Case");
        horizontalBox_2.add(up);
        low = new JButton("Lowercase");
        horizontalBox_2.add(low);

        verticalStrut = Box.createVerticalStrut(20);
        verticalBox.add(verticalStrut);

        low.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                tf.setText(tf.getText().toLowerCase());
            }
        });

        up.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                tf.setText(tf.getText().toUpperCase());
            }
        });

    }

    private class HandlerClass implements ItemListener {
        // For Checkboxes
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
            Font font = null;

            if (boldbox.isSelected() && italicbox.isSelected())
                font = new Font("Segoe Print", Font.BOLD + Font.ITALIC, 15);
            else if (boldbox.isSelected())
                font = new Font("Segoe Print", Font.BOLD, 15);
            else if (italicbox.isSelected())
                font = new Font("Segoe Print", Font.ITALIC, 15);
            else
                font = new Font("Segoe Print", Font.PLAIN, 15);

            tf.setFont(font);

        }
    }

    public static void main(String arg[]) {

        caseconversion go = new caseconversion();
        go.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        go.setSize(400, 250);
        go.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: You need for such things a LayoutManager. Search for this and learn :D http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can add BorderLayout as follows, for the JTextField :

```
add(tf,BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

and add 2 JPanel items :-

```
private JPanel panel1;
private JPanel panel2;
```

and initialize them into constructor as follows:-

```
panel1  =new JPanel();
panel2  =new JPanel();
```

and add this code

```
panel1.add(boldbox);
panel1.add(italicbox);
add(panel1,BorderLayout.CENTER);

panel2.add(up);
panel2.add(low);
add(panel2,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

I hope this help you.